# UITableViewController done manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If I use the Empty template in Xcode, which just gives an app delegate and window, and I want to have a UITableView with navigation bar for drilling up and down, am I correct in assuming I should just do as below, create a UITableView subclass, instantiate it, then instantiate a navController, set the TableView as the navControllers root view and then add the navController as the root view of the Window?

It seems wrong to create a UITableViewController only to add this to another view controller subclass (UINavigationController).

Is this correct?

```
    MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:MyTableViewController];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Comment: Note that there is a UITableViewController and a UITableView.  The former is just like any other view controller, while the latter is a "view" and can be added to other views (including a view controller's view) just like a label can.  You might want to consider which serves your purposes better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. That is how you use navigation controllers. They manage other view controllers. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW27)

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate it!

Comment: @EliGanem I always accept answers! Unfortunately there is that stupid 10 minute wait before you can accept an answer, not to mention the silly minimum comment length. not being able to say "Thanks" instead of 'Thanks alot!" is silly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct. The navigation controller is a container whose purpose is to manage a stack of view controllers so it's very different to the table view controller. Try the master detail template and compare the differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I'd also recommend you use a table view framework (such as the free Sensible TableView) to manage all your detail view controllers instead of you having to create them manually.